# Delete picture taken from camera

Tags: java, android, camera, gallery

I'm trying to delete the picture just taken by the app because I already saved it to my tmp folder for later use and I don't want the picture to show up in the gallery.
Problem is that I can't figure out how to do it, I tried a bunch of things and now I'm stuck.
This is my latest code (the data in the `onActivityResult` is null and I don't know why):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PIC && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri path = data.getData();
        new File(path.getPath()).delete();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture taken!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    CheckBox ckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cmark_picture);

    if (ckBox.isChecked())
        takePicture(view);
}

private void takePicture(View view) {
    tmpImg = new File(TMPDIR, "tmp.png");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tmpImg));
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PIC);
}
```

Comment: tmpImg is the File object that points to the picture. So use that.

Comment: That points to the temp picture, I'd like to delete the one in the gallery

Comment: No. That points to the only picture there is.

Comment: Then is my phone's fault, because it saves a picture in the gallery with a different name than tmp.png

Comment: Mmmm.. maybe because you force a .png. Try with a normal .jpg. What is TMPDIR ?

Comment: I just tried with .jpg, .jpeg and .bmp, still not working, it saves 2 pics, one in the gallery and one in the tmp folder.

Comment: `one in the gallery`. What do you mean? The gallery is no storage place. It is just an app that shows images on your device. Tone in the galleryo do so it makes a database of thumbs. You are looking at a thumb.  Please tell the file path of  both. There is only one file.

Comment: one is in "/ParkIt/tmp" and the other one is in /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_blabla

Comment: /Parklt ? That is only possible on a rooted device. Or it is not a full path. What is TMPDIR ????

Comment: Yeah, i forgot the rest, it's /sdcard/ParkIt/tmp

Comment: /sdcard/ParkIt/tmp.png?

Comment: /sdcard/ParkIt/tmp/tmp.png
My fault, i linked the full path picture included in the camera one and not in this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for deleting the captured image after completion of your purpose

```
File casted_image = new File("path of image");
                if (casted_image.exists()) {
                casted_image.delete();
                }
```